# Why does the python while loop below never break? Its a simple bot that does nothing but turn till its facing a target

Tags: python, pyautogui

```
def turn():
x=0
while x==0:
    #the players X co-ordinate, and the players Y co-ordinate is set to 513,437 respectively
    player_x, player_y=513,437
    #It looks for the HP bar of the monster, and then notes down the location in terms of left, right, height in the variable target (or target2, whichever it detects.)
    target = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(os.path.expanduser(r'~\Desktop\wow bot\references\target.png'),
                                      region=(0, 0, 1024, 768), confidence=.7)
    target2 = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(os.path.expanduser(r'~\Desktop\wow bot\references\target2.png'),
                                       region=(0, 0, 1024, 768), confidence=.7)
    #this turns the target location into an X, and Y format. So the location of the mob gets turned into x and y position and stored in target_x and target_y
    if target is not None or target2 is not None:
        global targety
        global targetx
        target_point=pyautogui.center(target or target2)
        targetx,targety=target_point
    #distance a = square root of target_y minus players_y to the power of 2
    distance_a=math.sqrt((targety-player_y)**2)
    #distance h = square root of target_X minus player_x to the power of 2 plus target_y minus player_y to the power of 2
    distance_h=math.sqrt((targetx-player_x)**2+(targety-player_y)**2)
    #inverse tan of distance a divide by distance h
    radian=math.acos(distance_a/distance_h)
    #turns radian into degrees
    theta=(radian*180/math.pi)
    #displays output of the degrees
    print((theta))
    direction=player_x-targetx
    print(direction)
    if theta >=25:
        if direction <=-1:
            keyboard.press('d')
            time.sleep(0.009)
            keyboard.release('d')
            if theta <=25:
                x=1
        elif direction >=1:
            keyboard.press('a')
            time.sleep(0.009)
            keyboard.release('a')
            if theta <= 25:
                x=1
```

I cannot understand why the code above does not break?  Its a simple bot that does nothing but turn till its facing a target. I want the loop to break so I can continue on another task afterwards.

Comment: I see a chance to break only if `theta` equals 25. Is your `theta` 25?

Comment: .. also, `direction` should not be equal to 0, in which case `x=1` is not reached.

Comment: @Austin Oh shoot! I didnt even think about that, how could I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop will break only at `theta=25` as your first `if` condition states that `theta>=25` and the nested if condition states that `theta<=25` then only `x=1` which is quite absurd, thus the condition is satisfied only for `theta=25`